# How to create a debian split package when using debhelper

Tags: debian, package-management

I have a debian package that I maintain whose source builds two separate pieces of software. I'd like to have it done so that it generates two packages when I build (foo-client and foo-server). The [PkgSplit](http://wiki.debian.org/PkgSplit) page on the debian wiki assumes that I'm using a hand-made `rules` file, but mine is done using premade debhelper rules. My `rules` file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

DEB_DH_INSTALL_ARGS = "--exclude=.svn"

include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/buildcore.mk
include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk

# this is run without fakeroot/sudo because we need the 
# users maven configuration for access to private repos, etc
build:
    /usr/bin/mvn clean package assembly:assembly -DskipTests=true

clean::
    rm -rf target
```

How can I change that so that it does what I need? I've added foo-server to the debian/control file (foo-client was there already) and it builds fine with the files under debian/ as foo-client.install, foo-client.dirs, etc. I've added the foo-server.install files et al, but it doesn't get built. How do I need to change the rules file to have it build both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was unrelated to this, it was a mistake elsewhere in the metadata files.